# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'

Tags: php, laravel

I have `product_variants` table where it relates 2 other tables data `products` and `variants`

When I try to update my product it returns this error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'field
> list' (SQL: update `product_variants` set `id` =
> 0118d682-970f-4859-b30b-e1c79df9c342, `parent_id` = ?, `name` =
> Interface, `slug` = interface, `photo` = ?, `type` = textarea,
> `active` = yes, `created_at` = 2020-08-05 14:57:42, `updated_at` =
> 2020-08-05 14:57:42, `pivot` =
> {"product_id":"4ea5f41f-aa2f-46d4-b033-e4e875cc8ff4","variant_id":"0118d682-970f-4859-b30b-e1c79df9c342"},
> `children` =
> [{"id":"7efe338d-9026-4fe8-b16f-6b99bc51871a","parent_id":"0118d682-970f-4859-b30b-e1c79df9c342","name":"1x
> RJ45, 1x SD (XC/HC) Card Reader, 1x (4K @ 60Hz) HDMI, 1x
> Mini-DisplayPort, 2x Type-A USB3.2 Gen1, 1x Type-A USB3.2 Gen2, 1x
> Type-C (USB3.2 Gen2 / DP), 1x Type-C USB3.2 Gen2x2","slug":"1x RJ45,
> 1x SD (XC/HC) Card Reader, 1x (4K @ 60Hz) HDMI, 1x Mini-DisplayPort,
> 2x Type-A USB3.2 Gen1, 1x Type-A USB3.2 Gen2, 1x Type-C (USB3.2 Gen2
> / DP), 1x Type-C USB3.2
> Gen2x2","photo":null,"type":"textarea","active":"yes","created_at":"2020-08-05
> 14:57:42","updated_at":"2020-08-05 14:57:42"}] where `product_id` =
> 4ea5f41f-aa2f-46d4-b033-e4e875cc8ff4 and `variant_id` in (0))

## Code

`product_variants` migrate

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('product_variants', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->primary(['product_id', 'variant_id']);
        $table->uuid('product_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->uuid('variant_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('variant_id')->references('id')->on('variants');
    });
}
```

`product model`

```
public function variations(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Variant::class, 'product_variants', 'product_id', 'variant_id');
}
```

`variant model`

```
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_variants', 'variant_id', 'product_id');
}
```

**Any idea what cause the problem?**

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to make your own [Pivot Model](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) and setup the primary key frankly:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class ProductVariants extends Pivot
{
   protected $primaryKey = ['product_id', 'variant_id'];
public $incrementing = false;
}
```

after this you should modify your relation:

```
public function variations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Variant::class)
                        ->using(ProductVariants::class);
    }
```

Comment: thanks but the thing is that i don't have `ProductVariants` model as this is relationship table (just get ids of two) it not required to have model for it (this table uses `sync` method to store data)